# vb.net/C# code editor with color coding

Tags: winforms, editor, text-editor

Are there any winforms source code editor controls available with color coding ? pref. open source

I seem to recall having come across something like that previously but can't seem to recall it ?

Comment: Why would you use something other than the free version of VS for .NET development?  You won't find a better editor.

Comment: Who said it was for mainstream development? Perhaps it's for a script editor for his own program?

Comment: You can "perhaps" all day, but the OP did not mention anything along those lines.  I'm not a mind reader...

Comment: Yes, it's a for a custom editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) is an open source syntax-highlighting editor component. There is an open source .Net wrapper utility on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=ScintillaNET).

Comment: This looks good, will try it out !

Answer (score 3):

SharpDevelop is an open source application that has an editor with color coding. You can check out how they implemented the color coding.

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/

Comment: Is there a stand-alone portion of the code editor perhaps as a control ?

Comment: I don't think you can just take their code editor as a control and put it in your project without touching the code. But this link might be a better idea for what you want:
http://laputa.sharpdevelop.net/AnnouncingSharpDevelopForApplicationsSDA.aspx

Comment: SharpDevelop is LGPL-licensed and has a WinForms control used in SharpDevelop 3.x and a new WPF-based editor called AvalonEdit for SharpDevelop 4 - http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Express?](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)

Comment: C# codng is best done in Visual Studio Express........:)

http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Comment: is that available as a winforms control ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple winForms control that will do syntax highlight, with an opensource license as you requested.

https://github.com/jmonasterio/AceWinforms/blob/master/README.md