# How to display C# source code from external file?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, parsing

For my project I'd like to display C# source code that I get from an external file. All I want to do is to parse that file and if possible display the code with syntax highlighting.

If also possible I'd like to divide the code I read into the various methods.

Where should I start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net/C# code editor with color coding ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111607/vb-net-c-code-editor-with-color-coding)

Comment: Actually that question is for WinForms controls whereas this is tagged WPF

Comment: Yes and I don't want to have an editor. I'd like to use it in my application, for example in a TextBox i draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [AvalonEdit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=AvalonEdit&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). It's easy to setup and use. Example

```
xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"

<avalonEdit:TextEditor Name="textEditor"
                       Loaded="textEditor_Loaded"
                       FontFamily="Consolas"
                       FontSize="10pt"/>

private void textEditor_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textEditor.Load(@"C:\MainWindow.xaml.cs");
    textEditor.SyntaxHighlighting =
        HighlightingManager.Instance.GetDefinition("C#");
}
```

Example Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This looks great, but from the documentation I read, it is more an editor than just a display?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Yes, it's a pretty big component that can do alot of stuff. If you set IsReadOnly="True" then editing will be disabled and it will just display the content of the file.

Comment: Thanks!This looks really nice! I was able todisplay a document. Now I just have to find out, if I can catch the event, if a user clicks on a method.And a way to change the click events into the surface specific events.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to launch an external tool or app like viewer. For example, in Windows you can use [VIM](http://www.vim.org/) app to open a cs file in read-only and no modification mode:

```
"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim72\gvim.exe" -R -M C:\test\MyClass.cs
```

Here are some codes to launch the tool:

```
public static int StartViewer(string file)
    {
        string parameters = string.Format("-R -M {0}", file);
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim72\gvim.exe";
        psi.Arguments = parameters;

        Process p = Process.Start(psi);
        p.WaitForExit();

        return p.ExitCode;
    }
```

I think VIM has CS syntax colorizer, or you can find some better one. It is free and has great search feature. However, VIM may not be good for none-VIM users. This is just an example. You can use other tools if you like to leverage other app strength.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to display the source code in the GUI elements of my applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on [syntax highlighting](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this for websites only?